# Why do I need to run an application as a root for the PAPI library to work?

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, papi

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. In my C++ applications I use the PAPI library, so I installed it from http://icl.utk.edu/papi/. However for some reason I can not run my applications anymore without having to type `sudo` in the beginning.

Even just typing `papi_avail` on the terminal to see which counters are available I get this:

```
================================================================================
  PAPI Preset Events
================================================================================
    Name        Code    Avail Deriv Description (Note)
PAPI_L1_DCM  0x80000000  No    No   Level 1 data cache misses
PAPI_L1_ICM  0x80000001  No    No   Level 1 instruction cache misses
PAPI_L2_DCM  0x80000002  No    No   Level 2 data cache misses
PAPI_L2_ICM  0x80000003  No    No   Level 2 instruction cache misses
..........
    Of 108 possible events, 0 are available, of which 0 are derived.

avail.c                                     PASSED
```

If I run `sudo papi_avail` I get this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Of 108 possible events, 50 are available, of which 17 are derived.

avail.c                                     PASSED
```

What changed in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

It is related with the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14227/do-i-need-root-admin-permissions-to-run-userspace-perf-tool-perf-events-ar). Theoretically, executing `sudo sysctl -w kernel.perf_event_paranoid=0` should be enough.